# APPHOST9613 InAppBrowser on Windows 8.1

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I get error code when I try to open a url on Windows 8.1. Code works on iOS and Android.

```
APPHOST9613
```

Any ideas why?